# Java Display 2 decimal with float variable

Tags: java

How can I display only 2 decimal points with float variable? I'm also using Scanner

```
float num;
System.out.println("Enter any number");
num = user_input.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Square of " + num + " is: "+Math.pow(num, 2));
```

Comment: Use `%2.2f`, number before decimal point is for the minimum number of characters used to display integral part, the number after is for the maximum number of digits included after decimal point.

Comment: are there some other ways? I mean I'm using square to display the float variable with 2 decimal places